# Ninject Factory extension vs. Lazy<T>

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions

I'm trying to inject a parameter that is evaluated lazily:

```c#
private readonly Lazy<IIdentifier> _userIdentifier;

public DocumentController(Lazy<IIdentifier> userIdentifier)
{
    _userIdentifier = userIdentifier;
}
```

`userIdentifier` isn't expensive to create, but this is a WebApi application, and `userIdentifier` is extracted from another object that depends on `HTTPContext`, which is null at `App_Start` time. Having to specify `Lazy` in the controller constructor seems like a code smell since the controller shouldn't need to know or care that this parameter needs special handling at composition time.

It's being injected like this:

```c#
kernel.Bind<IIdentifier>()
      .ToMethod(x => kernel.Get<IMinimalSecurityToken>().UserID);
```

I don't think I can use the Ninject Factory extension in this case, since it isn't as simple as newing up an instance of the object. I'd rather not write a factory just to handle this case, although I suppose that would be preferable to sticking the `Lazy` into the controller, so I'm hoping that there is some way to use the automatic factory from Ninject that I'm just not thinking of.

Comment: Curious as to why you're not using IMinimalSecurityToken as your dependency for the controller rather than this?

Comment: Because it carries around a whole bunch of baggage that the controller doesn't (and shouldn't) know about. The controller only needs the user to do its work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you don't want to use a factory and I agree a factory doesn't quite suite the use case here. Instead you can use a provider to serve you a token.

```
public class MyIdentityProvider : Provider<IIdentifier>
{
    ...
}

kernel.Bind<IIdentifier>().ToProvider<MyIdentityProvider>();
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer since this is what I did do, but it exposed another issue that is specific to my situation. It turns out that our identity provider uses HTTPContext, so I did need to use a factory (it turns out that the Lazy solution wasn't working once I tried to do anything with the identity). Absent that requirement, the presented solution is preferred.